# Editorial manager system and Firefox password manager

Tags: peer-review, editors, journal-workflow

This is maybe a rather special specialist question... I review and hold Associate Editor positions for various Elsevier and Springer journals that use editorialmanager.com (actually I believe both publishers have journals that use this, but it could be that Elsevier and Springer normally use different systems but the problem happens on both of them - the old Springer one that is, before transferring to Springer Nature Snapp, which comes with its own problems, therefore isn't used yet by every Springer journal, but has this one solved). Each time I'm invited to review, I get a new account name assigned. I can't memorise all these accounts and passwords, so I use Firefox's standard password manager, but this doesn't really help, because Firefox doesn't memorise the specific journal. It apparently only memorises editorialmanager.com (should be editorialmanager.com/specific_journal_webpage), so all these different accounts and passwords are saved, but whenever I have to log into a journal webpage, Firefox doesn't know which account is the right one and will offer me all of them. There are 10 or more now and I never remember which one belongs to which journal, so ultimately I have to reset the password to access my account.

Is there any way to get Firefox to memorise where exactly an account and password belongs (as works on other web pages)? What's wrong with editorialmanager (and/or Firefox) that this kind of thing happens? Do other browsers do a better job with this? (Otherwise I really like my Firefox though.)

Comment: Maybe better to ask at the [Web Apps stack](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/).

Comment: I talked to my local IT department for the same issue. Apparently there is no solution to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mozilla decided [long ago](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=263387) to not do this as it would likely break the password manager on more sites than it would help. Using a browser plug in for a separate password manager with autofill and more detailed URL filtering functionality is probably the easiest option for these sites.